# Linux Server Virtual Networking

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, ipsec

I have a Linux (CentOS 6) database test server which is often inaccessible so therefore a terrible way to test.

I was wondering if anyone has any recommendations for remote access to the server although I don't really want to use OpenVPN.

IPsec has been popping up a lot in my Google searches and seems really appealing over SSL. Are there any free IPsec client software packages that anyone can recommend or is it better to do it from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

SSH. Install openssh-server. Where is this server located? Make sure port forwarding is configured correctly for ssh to this server. If you have a dynamic IP address, use a service like dyndns.